# Is the Elo "rule of 400" a variation on EWMA?

Tags: self-study, exponential-smoothing, elo

**tldr:**
The Elo rule looks like an ewma-style running average to me.  Is that right?

**Details:**
The Elo rule of 400 ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system#Performance_rating)) could be expressed this way:
$$ rating_{N} = \frac{1}{N} \Sigma_{i=1}^{N}\left( r_i + sign\left(w_i \right)\cdot 400\right) $$

where $r_i$ is the rating of the ith opponent at time of play, $w_i$ is whether the game was won or lost, and $rating_N$ is the rating of the player of interest after the $N$th game.

With a little algebra this can be rephrased as:
$$  rating_{N} = \frac{N-1}{N \cdot \left( N-1 \right) } \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \left(r_i + sign\left(w_i \right ) \cdot 400 \right ) + \frac{1}{N} \left(r_N + sign\left(w_N \right )\cdot 400 \right ) $$

or

$$  rating_{N} = \frac{N-1}{N  } \cdot rating_{N-1} + \frac{1}{N} \left(r_N + sign\left(w_N \right )\cdot 400 \right ) $$

Which is the EWMA running average operating on the opponents rating and whether the game was won or lost.

Comment: The `rule of 400` is a linear approximation of the logistic Elo curve:

`E(Ra - Rb) = (Ra - Rb) / (4 * 200) + 50%`.

where 200 is the Elo class interval, and 1/4 is the slope at x = 0.